# Delphi REST client with certificate files: How to include cert.pem and cert.key in the code?

Tags: delphi-10.4.2

Delphi Rest send request with certificate?
In the code I need to include the certificate files (cert.pem and cert.key).
Thank you very much in advance.

1. function teste(): WideString;
2. var
3. restClient: TRESTClient;
4. restRequest: TRESTRequest;
5. restResponse: TRESTResponse;
6. begin
7. restClient := TRESTClient.Create('');
8. restRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(restClient);
9. restResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(restClient);
10. 
11. try
12. try
13. restclient.accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';
14. restclient.acceptcharset := 'utf-8, *;q=0.8';
15. restclient.autocreateparams := true;
16. restclient.allowcookies := true;
17. restclient.baseurl := 'https://mtls-mp.hml.flagship.maas.link/auth/realms/matera/protocol/openid;
18. restclient.contenttype := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
19. restclient.fallbackcharsetencoding := 'utf-8';
20. restclient.handleredirects := true;
21. restresponse.contenttype := 'text/xml';
22. 
23. restrequest.accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';
24. restrequest.acceptcharset := 'utf-8, *;q=0.8';
25. restrequest.acceptencoding := '';
26. restrequest.client := restclient;
27. restrequest.method := rmpost;
28. 
29. restrequest.synchronizedevents := false;
30. restrequest.response := restresponse;
31. 
32. restrequest.params.add;
33. restrequest.params.items[0].name  := 'grant_type';
34. restrequest.params.items[0].value := 'client_credentials';
35. restrequest.params[0].kind := pkgetorpost;
36. restrequest.params[0].contenttype := ctnone;
37. 
38. restrequest.params.add;
39. restrequest.params.items[1].name  := 'client_id';
40. restrequest.params.items[1].value := 'teste-hml';
41. restrequest.params[1].kind := pkgetorpost;
42. restrequest.params[1].contenttype := ctnone;
43. 
44. restrequest.params.add;
45. restrequest.params.items[2].name  := 'client_secret';
46. restrequest.params.items[2].value := '12345678';
47. restrequest.params[2].kind := pkgetorpost;
48. restrequest.params[2].contenttype := ctnone;
49. 
50. restrequest.execute;
51. result :=
52. except
53. on e: exception do
54. begin
55. result := restresponse.content;
56. end
57. end;
58. finally
59. restclient.free;
60. end;
61. end;